# How to show all subterm nodes of a parent term with the simple_hierarchical_select module?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I use drupal 7 and [simple_hierarchical_select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module.

I have a vocabulary called "news group" that has two level term (parent term and subterm) like the attached picture:

[image: terms and subterms chart image]

When I use exposed filter and simple hierarchical select for this (select term reference filed for "news group vocabulary") views filters show me two select list.first level list show parent terms (like HSE) and when select any option from first select list another select list appear that contain subterms of this parent term (like 5 subterm of HSE term) So I must select a option from **Secound select list (subterms)**  to have any result for my view.

I want to filter views results by first level (parent term) of taxonomy (like HSE) . But the Simple_hierarchical_select module Does not support first level of terms.must select deepest term for result.

I am not selected "force use to select deepest level" in field settings of term reference field.

Is any way to force SHS module to filter **all subterms of a parent term**?  Is another module for add "select all subterms of a term" feature to views exposed filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this issue solution after 2 weeks searching and experiments.
in views filter add "Simple hierarchical select - taonomy **with dept**" and in dept field of **settings of this filter select 1** . 
Now , when select a parent term , secound term with dept 1 has been showing too.